# RDLC add page breaks only if argument is set

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I need to have the option of dynamic page breaks on a report, my software allows you to choose to show the entire report on screen or if selected it would split the report via the tablix and then auto-scroll through the report every 20 seconds.

I can change the page by using report1.CurrentPage++ but how do I go about having a dynamic page break setup?

Any ideas?  The data is loaded from a custom Class object.

So default view is (no page break set)

```
+----------------------+
|col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
+----------------------+
|val1  | val 2 | val 3 |
|val 4 | val 5 | val 6 |
+----------------------+
```

And with page break set

```
+----------------------+
|col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
+----------------------+
|val1  | val 2 | val 3 |
+----------------------+
[PAGE BREAK HERE]
+----------------------+
|col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
+----------------------+
|val 4 | val 5 | val 6 |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: What code do you have or have you tried so far.. it would help to see what code you have.. nice illustration btw

Comment: @DJ KRAZE :At present I am unable to access the report itself via code, I've used the RDLC designer in Visual studio to create it as it has nested sub-reports as well.  I know it can be done with page breaks after groups but when I try this the hole report goes wrong and will only show a single group not all of them.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: The entire report works as it should no problems.  Now I just need to give it the option of page breaking if requested by the user.

Comment: If they want to page break.. how or what will determine where the break happens.. are you building the report in a loop .. or does the control have a pagebreak property.. ??

Comment: The first report has a Tablix which holds a group by clause.

Comment: If that code is working correctly i.e the GroupBy portion.. you will need to duplicate the code but based on if the use wants to Break you will need to change the code in that portion if you could show code it would be much easier to help.. for example what does the group by SQL look like..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: It is ran on a custom Object as the report itself has nested queries to retreive the data from the database and its not possible to generate the report from sql data.  So far my only solution is to duplicate the report and set page break after to true and depending the method they want load up the correct report :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this was to create a duplicate of the report and set the page break after to true, then depending on the options it would load either the non-page breaking report or the page breaking report.

Answer (score 0):

My solution,

add new parameter for the page break,
ex: `@PageBreak` `boolean` or `string`, up to you.

Next, you can create **group row** in tablix,
and set your **group on** to function,
something like this:

```
=IIf(Parameters!PageBreak.Value=true, Fields!YourGroup.Value, "")
```

then OK.

*you can delete the row or column that is created when you do this, without removing the group (remove row/ column only)

Next, find your group list (usually at bottom screen, **Row Groups**),
and set properties **Group** -> **`PageBreak`** = **Between**

This will do.

Hope this help.